# Rails migration to add Primary Key to Existing table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a table with two columns `employee_id` and `manager_id` without the primary key in Mysql. Employee and Employee_Manager have many to many relationships. In order to update the record, I need a primary key on the `Employee_Manager` table. Hence, in rails how can generate a migration which adds a column to existing table id(primary key) and set row value for all records in the existing table.

Comment: No table is having just two columns.There is no id or autoincrement column in it.That table was added in our app to use as join table without any model.

Comment: So, If you want to update the existing record, then you need both `employee_id` as well as `manager_id`

Comment: Yes, I need to add id column to existing table by populating id with row value for each rows.

Comment: you don't need an `id` column in `employee_manager` table. you can always find a record by through `Employee.find(employee_id).managers` and this would give you list of all managers and then you can always do something like `Employee.find(employee_id).managers.find(manager_id)` to find the record you are looking for.

Comment: `emp_manager = EmployeeManager.where(employee_id: self.id, manager_id: manager.id).first
emp_manager.update_attribute(:from_date, Time.now)`
Trying to do this but i get an error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'employee_manager.' in 'where clause': UPDATE `employee_manager` SET `from` = '2018-09-09 12:24:00' WHERE `employee_manger`.`` IS NULL):

Comment: Yes even this works.

Comment: It's not working.May be the reason is this https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/359-how-to-fix-unknown-column-id-in-where-clause-error-when-using-has-many-through
That'y I need a way to add id column with values to existing table

Comment: The error is becuase you are trying to update a column `from_date` in `EmployeeManager` table which is not even there.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I have added two new columns `from_date` and `to_date` in that table.

Comment: Can you try this query `EmployeeManager.where(employee_id: self.id, manager_id: manager.id).first.update(from_date: Time.now)`. see if it still throws an error

Comment: EmployeeManager.where(employee_id: 120, manager_id: 75).first.update(from_date: Time.now)
  EmployeeManager Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `employee_managers`.* FROM `employee_managers` WHERE `employee_managers`.`employee_id` = 120 AND `employee_managers`.`manager_id` = 75 LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: private method `update' called for #<EmployeeManager:0x0000000669d7b8>
from /home/smriti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.9/gems/activemodel-3.2.22/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:404:in `method_missing'

Comment: you might wanna use `EmployeeManager.where(employee_id: 120, manager_id: 75).first.update_attributes(from_date: Time.now)` considering that you are on rails 3.2

Answer (score 0):

In order to update the record on the association, you don't need an `id` column in the table.
you can always run a query like below:

```
EmployeeManager.where(employee_id: 120, manager_id: 75).first.update_attributes(from_date: Time.now)
```